# VTD XML - Buffer reuse

Tags: xml, performance, vtd-xml

I am planning to use the BufferReuse feature in VTD. Did a POC which works as desired. But I have a basic design question. Here is my problem statement: 
I have close to 1000 XML files in my application, which will be loaded and parsed often. Like ~(10-20) times in a sec. The 1000 XML files could range from <1KB - ~1MB. So to optimize the code, I thought of using BufferReuse.

My questions are: Does the code internally have a maximum limit of the number of XMLs or collective size of XMLs that will be handled by BufferReuse feature? Will it load the server too much given that in worst case, I will have 1000 MB(1000 files* 1MB) of XML? Where does it store these parsed objects? I was planning to implement a caching layer which will store the VTDNavigator for each xmls (with timeout and maximum size that can be cached). If I implement bufferReuse, will it in effect do the same thing for me or is there any difference there?

This code will ultimately be deployed in a pretty robust server with very good specs.

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and in what way did that not work?  Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Let me clarify: I have not faced any issue thus far and we are testing the code. This is more of a design question. I am wondering what would be the best way to implement 1) Use Buffer-Reuse option 2) Implement my own configurable cache with max limit (size, timeout) etc 3) Combination of both. My concern is because there are 1000 xml files and the size varying from less than 1KB up to 1MB, will buffer reuse store all the 1000 and for how long? Will it put too much of load in my system?

Comment: Modified my question to present the facts right and in logical order. Hope it makes sense now!

Comment: Are you processing those files one at a time? Buffer reuse is best when you are processing files that are similar in size...also buffer reuse will not overload server too much in ur case, if i understand your use case well enough... it does not store those object. It merely kept those used vtd buffers for a later use, instead of set them null for garbage collection...

Comment: The XML files will be processed at different times during run time based on when an operation is invoked. And you summed up my intent of using Buffer Reuse well. But since, the XML files are not of same size, do you  think it will still be a good idea to use Buffer Reuse?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author - Also, do you thinking building a caching mechanism to store VTDNavigator would be of any use here to boost the performance? Just to clarify, I intend to keep building the cache as and when the operation is invoked. So, after parsing the XML, the code will add the VTDNavigator to the cache for future use.

Comment: It is hard to judge whether caching is a good idea based on the information given in your writing so far. Notice that if you cache, you are storing those objects/buffers in memory, which may be performance adverse. Have you considered indexing those xml using VTD+xML format? It basically dumps vtd index along with xml files on disk so you can later on decide to read it back in, only to save the time of parsing entirely...

Answer (score 2):

There are usually the following ways to optimize performance with VTD-XML:

1. White space option- You can ask VTDGen to ignore or retain trivial white space characters. By default, VTDGen throws away
   those trivial white spaces. The difference is mainly in memory usage.
2. Buffer reuse- You can ask VTDGen to reuse VTD buffers for the next parsing task. Otherwise, by default, VTDGen will allocate new buffer for each parsing run. This optimization technique is most useful if you are processing similar sized XML file, so that the VTD buffer page size remains unchanged across consecutive parsing runs.
3. Adjust LC level- By default, it is 3. But you can set it to 5. When your XML are deeply nested, setting LC level to 5 results in better XPath performance. But it increases memory usage and parsing time very slightly.
4. Reuse XPath: Compiling/selecting XPath is a relatively slow operation, especially when you run XPath expression over many small files. The key is to take any AutoPilot.selectXPath() out of loops and reuse them by calling ap.resetXPath().
5. Use VTD+XML indexing- Instead of parsing XML files at the time of processing request, you can pre-index your XML into VTD+XML format and dump them on disk. When the processing request commences, simply load VTD+xml in memory and voila, parsing is no longer needed!!
6. The overwrite feature aka. data templating- Because VTD-XML retains XML in memory as is, you can actually create a template XML file (pre-indexed in vtd+xml) whose value fields are left blank and let your app fill in the blank, thus creating XML data that never need to be parsed.

option 1 2 3 and 4 usually improve performance incrementally. option 5 and 6 enable paradigm shift by fundamentally changing the way XML data are generated and consumed and giving you potentially vast performance improvements over existing processing framework and methodology. For one thing, you can easily figure out that the result of xpath evaluation can also be persisted along with VTD index to actually bypass the XPath evaluation. There are just so many ways to improve your apps that i will leave this to your imaginations.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is realtime that needs the XML to parse immediately, point #5 is not an option right?

As for point # 5, can you please elaborate how to replace the template XML with the field value from an incoming field?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you consider initiating a new question so it is more appropriate for me to focus on the subject, also can help more people as it is a more appropriate q and a in its own right...